# How can I get data from parent ViewController to child ViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[Flow diagram of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGzeF.png)

I'm a newbie in programming and I'm trying to build an ios app with the views as shown in above diagram. I retrieve data from Firebase into collection view of Main ViewController. The data model is as below.

```
struct DataCellViewModel {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var logo: URL?
}
```

When a cell of that collection view is selected, the respective Detail View is opened which has 3 child views. Some parts of the codes in Detail View are as follows.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var detailModel: DataCellViewModel
    
    private let detailVC1 = ChildOneViewController()
    private let detailVC2 = ChildTwoViewController()
    private let detailVC3 = ChildThreeViewController()
    
    init(detailModel: DataCellViewModel) {
        self.detailModel = detailModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "\(detailModel.name)"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground        
        addChildren()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    private func addChildren() {
        addChild(detailVC1)
        view.addSubview(detailVC1.view)
        detailVC1.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: view.width, height: 150)
        
        addChild(detailVC2)
        view.addSubview(detailVC2.view)
        detailVC2.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: toggleView.bottom, width: scrollView.width, height: scrollView.height)
        detailVC2.didMove(toParent: self)

        addChild(detailVC3)
        view.addSubview(detailVC3.view)
        detailVC3.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.width, y: toggleView.bottom, width: scrollView.width, height: scrollView.height)
        detailVC3.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

All 3 child views need to get parameters of `detailModel` of parent view so that they can show related data. But I'm not sure how to get it. I cannot directly call like 'DetailViewController.detailModel.name` from child views. Could you please tell me how to et it? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: In child controller , you can get parent controller like this (self.parent as? ChildOneViewController).

Comment: Initialise the child view controllers in the `init(detailModel:)` and pass the `detailModel` to them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have all 3 classes of child view controller conform to the same protocol. Loet call it DetailVCProtocol:

```
protocol DetailVCProtocol {
   var detailModel: DataCellViewModel
}
```

...

```
class ChildOneViewController: xxx, DetailVCProtocol {
    var detailModel: DataCellViewModel
    //  ...
}
```

Then pass the detailModel to each child view controller as it changes, and have a didSet on each child view controller update the display as needed.